# Please need help with my mess

Tags: installation, command-line, drivers

I really wanted to try out something different then Windows 7. So I installed Ubuntu and I have no clue on how to work it. I’m totally lost and have been trying to go back to windows by using the windows disc I made my recovery of, and its not working like Im trying. I have a Toshiba Satellite L655-S5096 windows 7 64 bit.

I have been trying to run different disc also like the rescue cd,dban 2.2.8, Dariks Boot and Nuke, to name a few..I guess Im so use to windows commands and cant get a grip on how to delete this so I can do a clean install of my Windows 7.

Could anyone please help walk me through deleting Ubuntu and installing windows back on here.

Comment: I just tryed with using the Windows Recovery CD, after I reboot it into the CD, it blinks a small line in the upper left corner of the black screen for a minute or so, untill the Ubuntu word shows up in the center with some dots flashing under the word like its loading. Then it will just boot up Ubuntu each time. I used a different recovery disc I had made and not it does the same thing at boot up except it stops before the Ubuntu word comes up. It stated having lines come across the screen as they went down for the last 5 minutes before it booted the rest of the way into Ubuntu.

Comment: The first of the two different lines read as followed by each number going up in number pattern. [807.859386] Buffer I/O error on device srO logical block 8. And the second line read as followed [816.374433] end_request: I/O error, dev srO, sector 64.  There were also Blocks 0,8. And sectors 0,16,128,64,512. It all came at me so quick that this is all I was able to get out of it. Now it booted into Ubuntu again..

Comment: plz check that you changed the boot-order in bios to recovery disk.

Comment: I cant get into my BIOS from forgeting the password which I dont even remember putting one in unless a virus hit it.. Who knows tho. Anyway, when I boot up I tap the f12 key and it gives me a boot order i get to pick from. Would the cd rom drive possibly be going out sence it hangs at the beginning? I have a friends external dvd drive which is a USB connection, and I can try to use it again. It just seemed like the last time I used it that when I pluged it in the SATA USB and picked the SATA at startup up that it wouldnt do anything..

Comment: did you put bios password?

Comment: I just turned on the pc with no disc in it and it went to the screen with the word Ubuntu on it, but on the bottom it said something that only stayed on the screen for a min and it said something like--- Press S to skip mounting, Press M to manual recovery and I didnt catch what the long letters and numbers were that it said if I wanted for a few seconds and then it booted up..

Comment: did you able to boot into ubuntu?then ran boot-repair,it will show you to boot windows os on startup.

Comment: /dev/sr0 is your CD-rom, which reports I/O errors. Either you drive is dying or the CD has errors.

Comment: I tryed to put in the only password in that I would of used for the BIOS and it didnt work..

Comment: see this http://superuser.com/questions/195909/resetting-a-bios-password-on-a-laptop

Comment: I just opened GParted Partition Editor and it shows 2 Partitions. The first says   /dev/sda1 with a key next to it, ext4, 295.22GiB, 10.43 GiB used, 284.79 GiB, boot.  The second partition says   /dev/sda2, ntfs, 2.87Gib, 15.20MiB used, 2.85GiB unused.

Comment: Im trying to load the Hiren's Boot CD to delete the password first if it loads

Comment: I just used the external dvd drive to put in the Hiren's CD and it booted up to a new screen that reads a good amount that is in 5 options on the top and 4 on the bottom. I will type this info in to see hopefully it will help with something..

Comment: 1.Ubuntu,with Linux 3.8.0-35 generic...2.Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-35-generic (recovery Mode)....3.Previous Linux Version....4.Memory Test (memtest86+)....5.Memory Test (memtest86+) serial console 115200).....

Comment: The is says.... Use the up key and the down key to select which entry is highlighted from the previous post I just sent.. Press enter to boot the selected OS., "E" to edit the commands before booting or, "C" for a command line.

Comment: I have already tryed the battery removal thing to reset the password, and my CMOS battery is no where to be seen without taking the laptop apart.. Im gona look into the website you sent me while I hear back to see if I should keep this page up incase I can use it for help somehow..

Comment: I clicked on the "C" for command line.. Its shows   grub>_

Comment: I typed "Help"... It gave me a page ful of commands. Any ideas on which ones to use to fix this? Thank you to all of you

Comment: Hi Rob! It is strongly advised against having long conversations in the comments section here. This problem is turning out to be a either a corrupt CD/CD drive, or boot order issue and that you don't have the password to the BIOS. Try creating a Windows bootable USB stick, plug it in, and restart. If it boots to it, then install Windows; it'll delete Ubuntu. If it doesn't boot to the USB, then your problem is the boot order/BIOS password, which is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: I totally understand. I actually am upgrading to Ubuntu to version 12.10. It said it had lots of things to load and to delete that wasent needed. Maybe I installed it wrong in the first place and I might learn how to use it and like it. I have the external dvd that does work cause Im using it on another laptop. But I will do what you said about the USB. Im gona get off here for a bit and take the kids sleeding for the start of the new year. Thank you for all your help and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you install Ubuntu. It could be actually because the boot for Windows 7 is actually locate in Windows RE partition instead of the main C: drive. I wonder this may help, but you can try to use Live CD or Live USB to determine your Windows RE partition still exist, and you might want to disable the grub.

To my knowledge, Windows RE partition is hidden in Windows, but when I use Linux to detect the partition, it usually located in dev\sdX3 or 4, (For Windows 8, the boot is somehow in a FAT32 partition), if grub is installed in sdX1 partition, your computer will read the grub and enters grub.

Hope this gives a wee bit information to help you further your quest of solving your answers.

Comment: Oh, by the way, check your partition using GParted. It will show you all the partitions of the hard disk.